# T-SQL how to repopulate fulltext index on a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing

I created a fulltextindex on some computed columns in my view, which had been created with `schemabinding` and given a unique clustered index so it could be fulltext indexed.

The computed columns concatenate several columns together with a space between them. Afterwards I noticed that there were nulls in some of these concatenated columns, which caused the concatenation to return null.

So I updated the underlying datatable with zero-length strings where there were nulls before.

Now I need to force a rebuild the fulltext index on the View.  What is the T-SQL statement to cause a complete rebuild?

I tried `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG <name> REBUILD` but the rebuild did not occur, although I got a Success message.